# Database error on aimeos install (Laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to install Aimeos to build a web shop using the [documentation](https://aimeos.org/docs/Laravel/Install_Aimeos).

But I'm getting this error:

> **[Aimeos\MW\DB\Exception]**
> Executing statement "CREATE INDEX users_status_address1_address2_index ON users (status, address1, address2)" failed: An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE INDEX users_status_address1_address2_index ON users (status, address1, address2)':SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

When I run

```
php artisan aimeos:setup --option=setup/default/demo:1
```

Can someone tell me what could fix this?

Comment: It says your specified key was too long, I think it's better to choose a smaller one.

Comment: You need to read the errors. It tells you everything.

Comment: It's an out of the box package, I haven't changed anything.

Comment: What database server and version do you use? The error seems to be misleading because the length of the status, address1 and address2 is only 6+255+255 chars. Maybe the collation (utf8_unicode_ci) plays a role.

Comment: Mysql 5.7.9. Part of the WampServer 3.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a change in MySQL 5.7+ that causes this problem. The fields in this index are of type smallint and varchar with utf8_general_ci collation. That causes the index to be 6+255*3+255*3+255*3 bytes long. Thus, it's 2301 bytes in total and much longer than the newly enforced 1000 bytes.

The Aimeos version 2017.01 fixes this problem by shortening the index.